# Why the following three strings's hashcode are same?

Tags: java, string, hashcode

After reading the source code of JDK, I am still surprised that the strings
`"AaAa", "AaBB" and "BBBB"` have the same hashcode.

The source of JDK is as follows,

```
int h = hash;
if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
    char val[] = value;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        h = 31 * h + val[i];
    }
    hash = h;
}
return h;
```

Anyone could clarify this?

Comment: Why exactly does this surprise you? Hash codes are not unique, there will be different strings with the same hash code, and you happen to have found three.

Comment: `"Aa"` and `"BB"` have the same hashcode. So sequences of `"Aa"` or `"BB"` of the same length will have the same hashcode.

Comment: @Jesper It can be surprising to someone why has experience with cryptographic hash functions that strive not to have collisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's how [the hash code is defined to be calculated for a `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--):

> The hash code for a String object is computed as
>
> ```
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```

So:

- For `AaAa`: `65*31^3 + 97*31^2 + 65*31 + 97 = 2031744`
- For `AaBB`: `65*31^3 + 97*31^2 + 66*31 + 66 = 2031744`
- For `BBBB`: `66*31^3 + 66*31^2 + 66*31 + 66 = 2031744`

Comment: looks it is very easy to clash? why choose this hash function?

Comment: @AdamLee because it is simple to calculate, works well on average. And it's part of the public API, so it's not possible to change it.

Comment: @AdamLee because making the finding of hash collisions hard was and is not one of the goals of this hash function.

Comment: @AdamLee Collisions are expected and not expected to be avoided or avoidable. Equal hashcodes do not suggest that objects are equal, but only they could be equal. See the Java [hashcode/equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) to get a better understanding of its purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Because [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability).

There are ~4 billion possible hash codes (`Integer.MIN_VALUE -> Integer.MAX_VALUE`) and basically infinite possible Strings. There are bound to be [collisions](https://learncryptography.com/hash-functions/hash-collision-attack). In fact, [the birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) shows us [that only ~77,000 strings](https://instacalc.com/52077) are required for a high chance of an arbitrary collision - and that would be if the hash function had extremely high entropy, which it doesn't.

Perhaps you are thinking of a [cryptographic hash function](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), where

> a small change to a message should change the hash value so
>   extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old
>   hash value

In which case, `Object.hashCode` is not designed for cryptographic purposes.

See also [How secure is Java's hashCode()?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52877/how-secure-is-javas-hashcode)

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that due to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox#Probability_table), you are more likely than not to have a hash collision with just 77,400 instances.

Comment: @AndyTurner How did you calculate 77k?

Comment: It's in the linked table, in the `p = 0.50` column, first row. How do I know it's 77.4k? Not sure - it's one of those factoids I just... "know". I may be misremembering :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Well remembered. Pretty much spot on... (added a link if you wanna pat yourself on the back)

Answer (score 3):

Their hash codes are

`AaAa: ((65 * 31 + 97) * 31 + 65) * 31 + 97 = 2.031.744`
`AaBB: ((65 * 31 + 97) * 31 + 66) * 31 + 66 = 2.031.744`
`BBBB: ((66 * 31 + 66) * 31 + 66) * 31 + 66 = 2.031.744`

That is just how the math is, nothing to be confused about.
Note the difference of exactly 31 between 97 and 66, that is what makes these hash codes line up so nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the description from Java documentation of `Object#hashCode` method：

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the object is modified.This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
>
> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
>
> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.  However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

So,the implementation of `String` class also maintain the above characteristics.So this is a normal phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of hash functions with different design and performance criteria.

1. Hash functions used for indexing such as associative arrays and similar usages can have frequent collisions with no problem because a hash table code will then handle that in some namer such as putting them in lists or re-hashing. Here it is all about performance in time. The Java `hash()` seems to be of this type
2. Another type of function, a cryptographic hash such as SHA*, strive to avoid collisions at the expense of hashing performance.
3. Yet a third type of hash functions is a password verifier hash which is designed to be very slow (~100ms is common) and may require large amounts of memory and not-to-frequent collisions are not a concern. The point here is to make brute force attacks take so long as to be infeasible.

Once choses the type and characteristics of hashes based on usage.